# Wordpress dynamic CSS with wp-load

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a dynamic css file that pulls information from the database e.g

```
header("Content-type: text/css");

require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

if ( get_option(PREFIX."_theme_base_color") <> "" ){
    $default_theme_colour = html_entity_decode(get_option(PREFIX."_theme_base_color"),ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); 
} else {
    $default_theme_colour = 'a3f088';
};
```

but I really hate using require_once('../../../../wp-load.php'); and there has to be a better way 
to loat "wp-load" into the file.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are using some kind of plugin , or theme with plugin codes.

If you are the developer , you can read here :

http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/

At any case ,you can use **bloginfo('wpurl');**  or is you have set a BASENAME than  **plugin_basename($file); **

if you are a simple user ,I suggest you leave that as it is .

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This is for my own theme, I don't really want to write up my css in the functions.php file. In regards to the  bloginfo('wpurl') I would still have to hard code the path echo get_bloginfo("wpurl").'/wp-content/wp-load.php'; Perhaps I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: well, my friend, There is nothing wrong being edantic when writing code . I know I am . :-) but IMHO - you do not have a choice . SOMEWHERE it needs to be defined. the shortest way I can think is this :  **site_url( 'wp-load.php' )** but I would recommend you to read the link I have posted, along with other info (google) on why it is not o good to include it .